# How to compute df for ARIMA models?

Tags: r, arima, degrees-of-freedom

Running this example from Hyndman's textbook in Chapter 9.1:

```
auto.arima(austa,d=0,xreg=1:length(austa))
ARIMA(2,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2  intercept  1:length(austa)
      1.0371  -0.3379     0.4173           0.1715
s.e.  0.1675   0.1797     0.1866           0.0102

sigma^2 estimated as 0.02486:  log likelihood=12.7
```

I wish to test if the trend is significant.

When using `lm`, I would need the degrees-of-freedom to get the p-values, e.g.:

```
tstats <- coef(test) / sqrt(diag(vcov(test)))
2 * pt(abs(tstats), df = df.residual(test), lower.tail = FALSE)
```

How do I compute d.o.f for this example (and in general for ARIMA models) to get the p-values?

Answer (score 3):

The df here are the same as for almost any other model: number of observations minus the number of estimated parameters. In this case, 31-4=27.

But you didn't need to know that here. The se is so small compared to the coefficient, you know the trend is significant without doing any formal tests.